# Getting an error message 'LinAlgError: Singular matrix' with full rank matrix while using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Python 3.7 and Numpy 1.16.5.

I tried to use the following code:

```
import numpy as np

M = [[np.eye(3), np.zeros((3,3))],[temp4, np.eye(3)]]
FTp = [[-0.0003],[0.0008],[0.0008],[0.0055],[0.0020],[0.0044]]
FT = np.linalg.solve(M,FTp)
```

The purpose of this code is to get a left division between `M` and `FTp` (FT = M\FTp).

`temp4` is a custom-valued 3x3 matrix. Whatever value `temp4` has, the matrix `M` should be full-ranked.

However, when I tried to run this code, I got the following message:

> LinAlgError: Singular matrix

What caused this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Probably because your matrix `M` is singular (i.e. non-invertible).

Comment: Actually, it looks like `M` is not a matrix.  Print it out yourself, `print(np.array(M))` or `print(np.array(M).shape)`.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq The result of ```print(np.array(M).shape)``` is (2, 2, 3, 3). I tried to make M as 6x6 matrix, but it seems that I failed to make desired M. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [np.block](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html) to create a 2d-array starting from 2d-blocks:

```py
import numpy as np

tmp = np.random.rand(3,3)
M = np.block([[np.eye(3), np.zeros((3,3))],[tmp, np.eye(3)]])
M.shape # (6, 6)

FTp = [[-0.0003],[0.0008],[0.0008],[0.0055],[0.0020],[0.0044]]
FT = np.linalg.solve(M,FTp)

FT
array([[-0.0003    ],
       [ 0.0008    ],
       [ 0.0008    ],
       [ 0.00477519],
       [ 0.0014083 ],
       [ 0.00380704]])
```